# MATCH ... AGAINST is not finding rows

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to do a search with `MATCH ... AGAINST`, but it doesn't give me any results. I have set `ft_min_word_len` to `2` and `ft_stopword_file` to `""`.

This is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE `rw_jam_search` (
  `jam` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`jam`),
  KEY `name` (`name`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `name_ft` (`name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

My data in the table:

```
jam name
53  Say Yes
54  testing
55  poijoik
56  stdd
57  Spartaaa!
58  Fearless
59  Mr. Mysterious
60  testmys
61  hello worlds
```

Why can't I find the row "Say Yes" with this query? It works if I use `LIKE js.name = 'say%'`.

```
SELECT *
FROM rw_jam_search js
WHERE MATCH(js.name) AGAINST ('say*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Comment: please `SHOW CREATE TABLE rw_jam_search`

Comment: @Teneff, take a look at "This is my table"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minimum length of the cached words by default is `3`, it can be changed in the configuration file:

```
[mysqld]
ft_min_word_len=3
```

so the word "say" will not be indexed for full text searches.
If you have access to mySQL's storage files you can use:

```
myisam_ftdump rw_jam_search.MYI 0
```

to list all the indexed words that will be included in the fulltext searches.

So if you try this query it should be working just fine:

```
SELECT * FROM rw_jam_search
WHERE MATCH(`name`) AGAINST('worlds')
```

**edit:** the asterisk(*) is quite different when used with `AGAINST()` check the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman//5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html)

Comment: From the link you given: *The asterisk serves as the truncation (or wildcard) operator. Unlike the other operators, it should be appended to the word to be affected*. Otherwise, +1.

Comment: I have already changed `ft_min_word_len`, that's not the problem. It wont find `hello words` either if I search for `hell*`, and it will find `Mr. Mysterious` if I search for `mr*`.

Comment: @Marwelln _The asterisk serves as the truncation (or wildcard) operator. Unlike the other operators, it should be appended to the word to be affected. Words match if they begin with the word preceding the * operator._ - check my edit

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. The words was not indexed in my fulltext index. After running `REPAIR TABLE rw_jam_search` they were there.